# Installed Ubuntu to my laptop and am stuck in Windows

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

Grub didn't overuse Windows boot manager and I can figure out how to boot from grub on the bios. I only have one drive and every time I boot to it it goes to windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool from Ubuntu or [EasyBCD](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml) to solve the issue. There are tons of resources/[how-tos](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/) in Ask Ubuntu and in the Internet. Post back if the above tools did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem:
I use HP so I had recovery partition ,I booted into windows recovery(F11 in my case).
Then went to Repair your computer...this should fix my problem But it couldn't find anything.So here is my solution:

1. go to troubleshoot in recovery menu.
2. Click Advanced options in Troubleshoot screen.
3. Click on command Prompt.
4. Type these following commands and hit enter after each line of command:

   ```
   Bootrec /fixmbr

   Bootrec /fixboot

   Bootrec /scanos

   Bootrec /rebuildbcd
   ```

It showed my C drive as windows and asked to add it as boot option .I said Y for yes and it Booted into windows 8.1 successfully.